# Google maps taking a long time to render in ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

The attached HTML renders very quickly in Chrome and Mozzilla browsers.  If I try to load it in IE11 I get several timeout errors and after 30 seconds the map finally renders.

I have tried all kinds of settings in IE11 with no luck.  When I run with developer tools on in debugger mode. I get the error 
InvalidValueError:not a string  in the following function 3 times

```
function wf(a,b){return function(c){if(a(c))return c;throw qf(b||""+c);}}function xf(a){var b=arguments;return function(a){for(var d=[],e=0,f=b[H];e<f;++e){var g=b[e];try{(g.Ff||g)(a)}catch(h){if(!(h instanceof pf))throw h;d[F](h.message);continue}return(g.then||g)(a)}throw qf(d[rd]("; and "));}}function yf(a,b){return function(c){return b(a(c))}}function zf(a){return function(b){return null==b?b:a(b)}}function Af(a){return function(b){if(b&&null!=b[a])return b;throw qf("no "+a+" property");}}
```

After hitting F5 to continue three times the MAP finally renders.

Here is the HTML.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--
 Copyright 2010 Google Inc. 
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0: 
 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
 -->
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Optimized Directions</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;
  var origin = " 1837 N. Kinser Pike, Bloomington, IN 47404 ";
  var destination = " 520 W NORTHLANE DR, BLOOMINGTON IN 47404 ";
  var waypoints = [];
  var markers = [];
  var directionsVisible = false;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var store = new google.maps.LatLng(35.930251, -86.824265);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: store,
      panControl: true,
      zoomControl: true,
      scaleControl: true
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
    calcRoute();
  }

  function addMarker(latlng) {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map,
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + String.fromCharCode(markers.length + 65) + ".png"
    }));    
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    if (origin == null) {
      alert("Click on the map to add a start point");
      return;
    }

    if (destination == null) {
      alert("Click on the map to add an end point");
      return;
    }

    var request = {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        waypoints: waypoints,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        avoidHighways: true,
        avoidTolls: true
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(directionsresult, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(directionsresult);
      } 
    });
    directionsVisible = true;
  }

  function updateMode() {
    if (directionsVisible) {
      calcRoute();
    }
  }

  function printTextDirections() {
    for (var i = 0; i < directionsresult.routes.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < directionsresult[i].legs.length; j++) {
        alert(directionsresult.routes[i].legs[j]);
      }
    }
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" style="font-family: sans-serif;">
   <div id='map_canvas' style='width: 65%; height: 580px; float:left; border: 1px solid black;'></div>  
   <div id='directionsPanel' style='width: 30%; height:580px; float:right; border; 1px solid black;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JSv3 Freezes for a few seconds every 30 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343055/google-maps-jsv3-freezes-for-a-few-seconds-every-30-seconds)

Comment: possible duplicate of [gmaps API v3 very slow loading on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344714/gmaps-api-v3-very-slow-loading-on-ie)

Comment: Are you running this from the local file system?

Comment: Don't see an issue in IE11 with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apyd1uyo/) (IE11.0.9600.17691 to be specific)

Comment: Also, don't see any issue in IE11 mobile (OS version: 8.10.14219.314/Lumia 520)

Comment: Yes I am running from local file system,  and that seems to be the problem?  I have all the security settings in ie11 set to allow local content to run from local drive.

Comment: Even added <!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost --> based on another post to stop the Ie from putting up blocked content message.

Comment: Look at the two other similar reports from today.  Perhaps try not using the [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) (specify v=3 in the API include).

Comment: According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx#The_Local_Machine_Zone_Lockdown), IE will never thinks the local zone is safe, therefore the weird behavior happened? Also, your `<!-- saved from url=(0016)localhost -->` should only have effect when you have a web server hosting your file locally, but not opening it directly from the file system...

Answer (score 2):

I specified the google maps version at 3.19 and the problem was resolved.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.19"></script>
```

I was getting the experimental version because I had no version specified.