# Google Map is shown as grey space in IE11 , Not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I use the google Map v3.exp API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp) to render the google map in our project , and Now In Chrome , the Map can be shown correctly in the corresponding area:

But in IE11 , it is only shown as partially not fully in that area , also if I zoom out and zoom in , it will be totally grey .
also checked the related topics , seems we could add the resize event: google.maps.event.trigger(that._oMap, "resize"),  but it is not helpful in this case . so is there any body faced the same bahaviour?

also I raise one issue to google : https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8842

Comment: Can you please create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

hi   No I ahve arleady fix it via down-port the google library from V=3.exp to V=3.  in V=3.expe , I face that issue which load a little picture , but not more , and if I Zoom our and Zoom in , the ma area will be missing , and thre is a similarquestion Which is already answered.[IE11 loading long time for Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356745/google-maps-taking-a-long-time-to-render-in-ie11)